# Jquery list inner property subselection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a very simple problem that consists in "extracting a list of property values from an array of jquery elements". I'm not that good in jQuery so I'm probably missing something quite obvious here.

Let's say I have a list made of li (that are to be selected with the jquery-ui selectable plugin):

```
<ol class="selectable" id="LeagueFilterEnum">
    <li>League</li>
    <li>Bronze</li>
    <li class="ui-selected">Gold</li>
    <li class="ui-selected">Platinum</li>
    <li>Master</li>
</ol>
```

I can select them like so :

```
var selectedElements = $("#LeagueFilterEnum li.ui-selected");
```

What I am looking for is a way to retrieve a set of each of these li's property "innerHtml", if possible in one line... something like this:

```
var selectedLeagues = $("#LeagueFilterEnum li.ui-selected").selectValues("innerHtml");
```

With my example, this would give me an array : ['Gold','Platinum']

I could use some .each() magic, but I am wondering if something better exists.

Have you any idea ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I see you fixed the selector after I answered. Please don't change the question using the answer, it makes them hard to understand.

Comment: I get it, but you were so fast ! My correction and your answer got online almost at the same time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
var selectedLeagues = $("#LeagueFilterEnum li.ui-selected").map(function(){
    return this.innerHTML
}).get();
```

Notes :

- I fixed your selector, it was wrong.
- the final `get` is to make a real array from the jQuery object returned by `map`

Comment: Yes I totally screwed up my selectors when typing it in here sorry ^^

Comment: That works great ! I just learnt map and this very use of get, thanks a lot.